# How to return a value from a nested API function

Tags: javascript, function, api, nested

I have a function called wikiCount that I'm using to wrap another function from an API like this:

```
 var wikiCount = function(wikiPage, word){

      wtf_wikipedia.from_api("Toronto", "en", function(markup){

        var obj = wtf_wikipedia.plaintext(markup)
        var a = obj.toLowerCase().split(" ").count(word)
        return a

    })
}
```

How can I return a value from the nested API function so that I can use it in the wrapper function. The whole purpose of doing this is because I'm trying to access the variable "a" outside the function.

Comment: What is the API? They probably have documentation or example code that would help with this.

Comment: There are answers to this question here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

A cool way is with promises:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function wikiCount(wikiPage, word){

     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        wtf_wikipedia.from_api("Toronto", "en", function(markup){

            var obj = wtf_wikipedia.plaintext(markup)
            var a = obj.toLowerCase().split(" ").count(word)

            resolve(a);

        });
    });
}

wikiCount('somePage', 'someWord')
.then(function(result) {
  // do something with the result
  // this is 'a' that you resolved in the function above
});
```

The above example uses the [bluebird promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html). If you're in a browser or a Node.js runtime that supports ES6, you can use [native `Promise`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

The above is referred to as "[Promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html)":

> Promisification means converting an existing promise-unaware API to a promise-returning API.